# She deposited some into the bank, hoping that at the end of each quarter she would have enough to cover the next bill from BGS

Tags: grammar

Why hope is in -ing form?
Does participle phrase used in this sentence?

Comment: Can you include in the question the source of the quote, please.

Comment: I doubt the cited text came from a native Anglophone. There are 8 written instances of [*deposited some **in** the bank*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deposited+some+in+the+bank%22) in Google Books, plus one [*deposited some **at** the bank*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deposited+some+at+the+bank%22). But unsurprisingly, none at all of [*deposited some **into** the bank.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deposited+some+into+the+bank%22) That last one is not an idiomatically valid preposition use in English.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a gerund-participle phrase.

This particular participle tells us the reason that she deposited money in the bank.

There are several ways in English to explain the reason for something. A participle is one way. However as you haven't provided much context (or the source of the quote) there not much more that can be said.